# My computer takes 2 minutes to load MS Excel. Is RAM the culprit?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, microsoft-office

My main laptop is broken and I am using my old one.  It performs office work slowly, and I was particularly upset when it took 2 minutes to load MS Excel.

I know this is not a specific question, but what aspects of the computer make for slow day-to-day operation?  Specifically, this laptop never used to run slowly, but since it is 7 years old it takes time to load programs.

My specs:
ASUS F5R, Windows XP, 1.37GB RAM
Intel Core 2 Duo T2080 @ 1.73GHz
120GB HDD @ 50% capacity

Again, I know it's not a specific question, so I would even appreciate a short reply like:  "Computer is 7 years old, check your registry."

Comment: looks like your hard disk is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

- If your pointer is slow, it's most certainly the RAM. Perform a test using memtest86+

Or

- If boot time, running applications and overall *file-related* operations are slow, it's most certainly the hard drive. Have you checked your SMART data? Your disk may be dying.

Comment: please don't use backticks for "highlighting"

Comment: @Sathya Is there a rule for that? What am I supposed to use to highlight the name of an application?

Comment: there's no need to highlight, excess formatting ruins the readability of a post. See Ruslan's post. http://superuser.com/a/774000/4377

Comment: @Sathya I'm sorry but highlighting *memtest86+* doesn't count as excessive highlighting in my opinion, and I think monotonous, unformatted long texts ruin the readability too. It may just be your personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you could drive to exclude the hard drive issue by booting your machine from Live CD. Apart of possible hardware issues of hard drive it could be very slow also because of fragmentation or old registry.

Do you have another copy of your Excel file. You can copy it as well (good reason to make backup if it's precious)

So, I would run to separate tests:

1) Boot your machine with Live CD and open this Excel file from your hard drive. By the way, most Linux distributions (for example take [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)) have LibreOffice which pretend to work same way like MS Office (earlier called in them as OpenOffice, which still exists by itself, but not currently in these modern OS by default, but that's another strory).

This approach would cover possible issues of big old (slow) registry and/or HDD fragmentation.

2) Conjoin 1. - boot from Live CD, and open copied version of Excel file, open the copy from a different storage. That would cover the possible hardware HDD issue.

Measure time in all tests and compare.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related exclusively to `Excel`, or that it even has something to do, since the OP said *office work*, generalizing the issue. I think running a test from the Live CD would be more than enough to know wether or not the disk is the problem.

Comment: I don't know why this question got downvoted.  These are great ideas.  Thanks!!